# Page slide animation with horizontal anchor navigation

Tags: theming

I want to realize a project with sliding pages (horizontally or vertically) similar to the one shown on www.viasko.de.

Is that possible with Drupal due to a different navigation concept via anchors, and not with urls? Does the URL dispatcher allow anchors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's menu system accepts paths like 'node/34#stuff' via the GUI, where 'node/34' is the internal path to a specific page (with the anchor). On the code level the [url()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function also allows to set an anchor via the 'fragment' option. So generally you shouldn't have problems with implementing anchor links in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

They used here element using html like map
example

```
<a href="#speisekarte" title="">
    Speisekarte
</a>
```

Here the point to start the page

```
<a name="speisekarte" id="speisekarte"></a>
<div>Desc</div>
```

If you don't find a module you can make it custom

Comment: thanks ahmed...i know how this works technically...but how to implement it with drupal url system?